# Place firebase images into an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am using icarousel and I want to place images I got from Firebase into an array and display the images in order. So I created a function. The maximum a user can post is 3 pictures at a time and I place those three pictures into an array.

```
 func bookImageArray() {
       databaseRef.child("books").child(self.postID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in


                //Check to see if a first image for the book exists
            if snapshot.hasChild("image"){
                if let stringImage = self.imageNames {


                    let imageRef = self.storage.reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com/images/\(stringImage)")

                    imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {


                            self.ImageOne = UIImage(data: data!)!
                            imageArray.append(self.ImageOne)


                         imageArray = [self.ImageOne]


                        }else {
                            print("Error downloading image:" )
                        }

                        self.carouselView.reloadData()
                        self.carouselView.type = .linear

                    })}
                print("image exists")
            }

            //Check to see if a second image for the book exists
            if snapshot.hasChild("imageTwo") {
                if let stringImages = self.imagesTwo {

                    let imageRefs = self.storage.reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com/images/\(stringImages)")

                    imageRefs.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {

                            self.ImageTwo = UIImage(data: data!)!
                            imageArray.append(self.ImageTwo)


                           imageArray = [self.ImageOne,self.ImageTwo]


                        } else {
                            print("Error downloading image:" )
                        }
                        self.carouselView.reloadData()
                        self.carouselView.type = .linear

                    })}

                print("imageTwo exists")

                //Check to see if a third image for the book exists
            }

            if snapshot.hasChild("imageThree") {
                if let stringImage3 = self.imagesThree {

                    let imageRef = self.storage.reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com/images/\(stringImage3)")

                    imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {

                            self.ImageThree = UIImage(data: data!)!
                            imageArray.append(self.ImageThree)


                            imageArray = [self.ImageOne,self.ImageTwo,self.ImageThree]

                        }else {
                            print("Error downloading image:" )
                        }

                        self.carouselView.reloadData()
                        self.carouselView.type = .linear

                    })}
                print("imageThree exists")

               }
            }
```

The images are placed into the array. However, sometimes my three pictures are not displayed and sometimes it only displays one picture. But then when it does display three pictures, the pictures are displayed in order. I am not sure why sometimes when I click the cell that is suppose to have three pictures, three pictures appear and sometimes two pictures appear or sometime one picture appears.

Answer (score 0):

No need to do the below because you are already appending the element.

```
 imageArray = [self.ImageOne]
```

Please check the below :

```
var imageArray:[UIImage] = []

func bookImageArray() {
    databaseRef.child("books").child(self.postID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        //Check to see if a first image for the book exists
        if snapshot.hasChild("image"){
            if let stringImage = self.imageNames {
                let imageRef = self.storage.reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com/images/\(stringImage)")

                imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        if let imageOne = UIImage(data: data!) {
                            imageArray.insert(imageOne, at: imageArray.count)

                        }
                    }else {
                        print("Error downloading image:" )
                    }
                    self.carouselView.reloadData()
                    self.carouselView.type = .linear
                })}
            print("image exists")
        }

        //Check to see if a second image for the book exists
        if snapshot.hasChild("imageTwo") {
            if let stringImages = self.imagesTwo {
                let imageRefs = self.storage.reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com/images/\(stringImages)")
                imageRefs.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        if let imageTwo = UIImage(data: data!) {
                            imageArray.insert(imageTwo, at: imageArray.count)
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("Error downloading image:" )
                    }
                    self.carouselView.reloadData()
                    self.carouselView.type = .linear

                })}

            print("imageTwo exists")

            //Check to see if a third image for the book exists
        }

        if snapshot.hasChild("imageThree") {
            if let stringImage3 = self.imagesThree {
                let imageRef = self.storage.reference(forURL: "gs://gsignme-14416.appspot.com/images/\(stringImage3)")
                imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        if let imageThree = UIImage(data: data!) {
                            imageArray.insert(imageThree, at: imageArray.count)
                        }
                    }else {
                        print("Error downloading image:" )
                    }
                    self.carouselView.reloadData()
                    self.carouselView.type = .linear
                })}
            print("imageThree exists")
        }
    }
})
print(imageArray)
```

Comment: without  `imageArray = [self.ImageOne]` the images do not display in order

Comment: the images display out of order, I will like for it to be displayed imageOne, imageTwo, imageThree

Comment: Instead of `append`, I used `insert`

Comment: it crashes and I get `fatal error: Array index is out of range`

Comment: Please let me know how you declared `imageArray`?

Comment: `var imageArray = [UIImage]()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155966/discussion-between-vini-app-and-juelizabeth).